# I don't have constant current in this circuit

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, constant-current, graph

I have problem with this circuit, which purpouse is to give constant circuit on R7 resistor. Why i can't get constant circuit? Is it problem with simulator? [image]

[image]

Comment: What's Vce of Q1? is it in forward active operation?

Comment: What current are you measuring through R7? Based on your values, it should be around 25uA,

Comment: Current should be 25uA

Answer (score 3):

25uA times 165.84kΩ (Rx = 0) is 4.1V

Your constant current source has a compliance that goes to about 3.4V, give or take, as the transistor goes into saturation. So it can never supply a constant current, even if Rx = 0.

There is 3.55V from the divider on the non-inverting input, if you allow 100mV for the transistor saturation (it's better to allow more if you want accuracy, since the gain of the transistor will already be fading, more like 1V is good) so you can have 3.45V at the most.

If you try to fiddle with this circuit to get it to work, you may also run into the input range limitations or output range limits of the OP07, so be careful of that.

BTW, it's unclear why you have R7 at all. It is doing nothing of value that I can see. If you short it out you'll have a useful range for Rx.

Also, please do not use 'Vdd' for negative voltages, use 'Vee'. And don't use 'Vee' for positive voltages. It's against established convention, even if you get the voltages correctly to the circuit.

Comment: Vcc and Vee are named from collector and emitter, and Vdd and Vss are for drain and source, so it also makes little sense to choose one from each pair.